# Can I query elasticsearch inside spark map method?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark

I can query elasticsearch from spark like this:

```py
spark.read.format(
    "es"
).options(
    **{
        "es.index.auto.create": "true",
        'es.resource': index_name,
        'es.nodes.wan.only': 'true',
        'es.nodes': elasticsearch_host,
        'es.port': elasticsearch_port,
        'es.net.http.auth.user': elasticsearch_user,
        'es.net.http.auth.pass': elasticsearch_password,
        'es.query': query
    }
).load()
```

but how can I visit es inside map method?

something like this:

```py
df.rdd.map(
 lambda x: query_es({"match": {"name": x[1]}})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by myself yesterday. The solution is relatively simple.

```py
df.rdd.map(
    lambda x: ElasticSearch().search(index=index, query={"match": {"name": x[1]}})
)
```

yes, just new an object of ElasticSearch() will works.
If you encountered obstacles in this step such as `Connection Error` or etc. Try set `xpack.security.enabled=false` and modify the procotol from `https` to `http`